# How to flip the orientation of beamsplitter in pst-optexp package in latex

Tags: latex, pstricks

I was trying to plot an interferometer in latex using pst-optexp package. Everything works fine the beamsplitter is in the wrong orientation and need to be fliped 90 degree. However, the command`\beamsplitter[bsstyle=plate, compname=BS,label = 0.8 -45](A)(BS)(PD){BS}` does not work. Does anyone know how to rotate the beamsplitter in that package?

The code I used is

```
\documentclass[margin=36pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](6,6)
\pnodes(0,3){S}(1,3){LS}(2,3){A}(3,3){BS}(5,3){M1}(3,5){M2}(3,1){PD}
\optbox[abspos = 0.5, optboxsize=1 0.5, labeloffset = 0](S)(LS){Laser}
\lens[compname=L0, lensradius=0.5 0.5, lensheight = 0.5, abspos = 0.2, n=2,thicklens = false](LS)(A){obj}
\pinhole[compname = PH, labeloffset = -0.7](LS)(A){Pinhole}
\lens[compname=L1, abspos = 1, n=2, thicklens = false](LS)(A){Lens1}

\psset{mirrortype=extended, mirrordepth=0.2}
\beamsplitter[bsstyle=plate, compname=BS,label = 0.8 -45](A)(BS)(PD){BS}
\optbox[abspos = 1.75, optboxsize=0.5 0.5, label = 0.7 180](BS)(M1){Sample}
\mirror[compname=M1,labeloffset = 1](BS)(M1)(BS){Test Arm}
\mirror[compname=M2, mirrortype=piezo](BS)(M2)(BS){Ref Arm}
\lens[compname=L2, label = 1 180](BS)(PD){Lens2}
\optdetector[compname=Det, dettype=round, label = 0.5 90,abspos = 2.5](BS)(PD){Camera}
\addtopsstyle{Beam}{beamwidth=0.2, fillstyle=solid, linecolor = red, fillcolor=red, opacity = 0.2}
\drawwidebeam(LS){L0}{L1}{BS}{M1}{BS}{M2}{BS}{L2}{Det}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The resulting picture is [the orientation of beam splitter is wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvwmW.png). The example given in pst-optexp manual is wrong in the same way.